# What model can I use to describe the following time-series?

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, modeling, arima

I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me locate an appropriate model for the following two time-series (the cyan and blue one, the reds are rolling means).

[image: [The time-series in question](http://i.imgur.com/pmXerft.png)]

I'm looking more for a general direction based on the attributes of the data rather than a "use this" answer. Otherwise I'll learn less. Though all assistance is welcome.

Comment: It's hard to give more detail because you haven't included any idea of what you want to do with the data. That said, R has a package called FDA (functional data analysis). You can read the first chapter here to see what kinds of questions you might be able to answer: http://www.kermanshahmet.ir/MyFiles/admins/xabar/file/ramsay_j__silverman_b__applied_functional_data_analysis___methods_and_case_studies_springer_2002.pdf

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

At the moment the idea is to get a model that can accurately replicate the existing data and forecast about 60 days into the future.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to know what the data is, but you might first consider adjusting them for seasonality effects. Using the rolling mean as a proxy for what the seasonally adjusted series might look like, I would test the two time series for cointegration since it looks like they could share a common trend (alternately, it could just be the result of strong correlation). This would suggest an error correction model or vector autoregression might be a good initial estimation strategy.

Comment: The data is item purchasing numbers per day from a company. The two series are just different sources for those purchases, so they should be related.

Any chance you could recommend a reading for testing for cointegration?

Comment: http://www.uh.edu/~bsorense/coint.pdf came up in google. You might also consider summing them up to weekly or monthly orders. What you should do also depends on what your goal is (i.e. do you just want a good fit or do you want to forecast, there might be other variables that are also related to forecasting purchases, particularly at a longer horizon, like the state of the economy or your industry).

Comment: Actually you're describing the method I'm currently employing, I've taken apart the series by month, week, weekday by subtracting the real score from the mean of each type. I'm planning on generating in-sample data next which minimizes my squared error on the weights of each of those parts. The reason I asked the question is because I consider this method rather "hacky", and the fact that I only have a year of data means the likelihood of overfitting will be very large.

Answer (score 1):

A possible option that has not been mentioned yet is to try to fit a type of univariate time-series model called an ARIMA model. Without being able to investigate the data further, I cannot say specifically which ARIMA would be appropriate for this data, nevertheless, ARIMA is an option worth considering. The only thing I could say is that it does look as though some degree of differencing would be required to induce stationarity (for both series).

Testing for cointegration, as already mentioned, looks like a good idea. Keep in mind that even if the two series are not cointegrated, you can still use a VAR (rather than a (vector) error correction model (VECM)).

I haven't said which particular model will fit this data (very difficult to answer without having the data!), but I have provided you with three *classes* of models that are worth investigating. There's actually a lot in that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you peruse [this](http://www.inside-r.org/howto/time-series-analysis-and-order-prediction-r) inside-R thread. It has R code, and on the face of it, your problem and that outlined in the link seem similar.

Comment: Thanks, signal decomposition looks like it might be interesting for working with this type of data.